# Multilingual support for custom validation messages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Hi let's say I have the following in my accounts model:

```
validates :name,  length: {in: 1..70, message:%Q|Please enter a decent name Sr.|}
```

How can I add multilingual support to those custom validation messages? I checked [this](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/i18n_mehrsprachige_rails_applikation.html) tutorial

But I could not find out how to translate custom validation messages in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed once to use translations in model so I went this way:

```
  TITLE = { 0 => :"employee.title.mrs",
            1 => :"employee.title.mr",
            2 => :"employee.title.miss" }
```

these are options for select, and in select I used `t(value_of_key_here)`, value was a string that was seen as a key to locale.

So in your case this might work (not really sure):

```
validates :name,  length: {in: 1..70, message: :"enter_decent_name"}
```

that would return a `key` in your validation messages and rails will just complain about missing `key` in translations that you have to add into your yml file:

```
enter_decent_name: 'Please enter a decent name Sr.'
```